# How to Print the odd number along with even if contains in sequence

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures

Here the code below is getting the output after removing the even digit but the case here is that

if any of the boxes contains odd digit it must print entire box number with the even number even if there is even number in between the odd digits

Condition: If the first box contains odd digit must not accept the box and print sorry 
Please check the code and the output i need is given in the expected  output block

```
import java.util.*;

class Chocolate {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the no. of boxes:");
        int no = sc.nextInt();
        if (no <= 0 || no > 10) {
            System.out.println("Invalid input");
        } else {
            int[] ch = new int[no];
            for (int i = 0; i < no; i++) {
                System.out.print("\nEnter the no. of chocolates in box " + (i + 1) + ":");
                ch[i] = sc.nextInt();
            }
            System.out.print("\nNo of chocolates in each box:");
            for (int i = 0; i < ch.length; i++) {
                if (ch[i] % 2 != 0) {
                    System.out.print(ch[i] + " ");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Original Output:

```
Enter the no. of boxes: 5

Enter the no. of chocolates in box 1: 4

Enter the no. of chocolates in box 2: 2

Enter the no. of chocolates in box 3: 3

Enter the no. of chocolates in box 4: 6

Enter the no. of chocolates in box 5: 1

No. of chocolates in each box: 3 1
```

Expected

```
Enter the no. of boxes: 5

Enter the no. of chocolates in box 1: 4

Enter the no. of chocolates in box 2: 2

Enter the no. of chocolates in box 3: 3

Enter the no. of chocolates in box 4: 6

Enter the no. of chocolates in box 5: 1

No. of chocolates in each box: 3 6 1
```

Comment: I don't completely understand your assignment but looking at the expected output I think you need to "look ahead" in your last loop so that you also check what comes next.

Comment: Do you have to include the possibility of multiple even numbers coming in between 2 odd numbers? Or is it always going to be a single digit?

Comment: it can come like 425221 kind of

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like

```
String s = "";
boolean x = false;
int odd = 0;
for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++) //a is your array
    if(a[i]%2!=0)odd++;
for(int i=0;i<a.length && odd>0;i++){
    if(a[i]%2!=0){
        x = true;
        s+=a[i] + " ";
        odd--;
    }else{
        if(x) s+=a[i] + " ";
    }
}
System.out.println(s);
```

Comment: sir doesn't bring me entire digits  for eg i took 23145 then the output should be 3145 i am getting only 314